# Rewrite url with part of it already existing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite an url, should be pretty simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

My htaccess file at the moment:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type" 

#Website
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule         ^actueel/(.*).html portfolio.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^info/(.*).html catlisting.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^nieuws/(.*).html nieuws.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I am using a joomla CMS, but since updating to the latest version I need to type out the url fully to end up at the correct page (I used to be able to just type websiteurl/cms now I have to type websiteurl/cms/administrator)

How can I rewrite it so when the url ends with /cms/ (or /cms) it adds /adminitrator at the end?

When I try the following I end up in an infinite loop:

```
RewriteRule         ^cms cms/administrator [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `^cms` is, that it matches anything starting with `cms`, also `cms/administrator`. To match only `cms`, you must anchor it at the beginning `^` *and* at the end `$`, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^cms$ cms/administrator [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.